# How to display number of post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have list like:

```
<ul id="portfolio-list">
   <li class="class1 class2">Content<li>
   <li class="class1 class2">Content<li>
   <li class="class3 class2 class1">Content<li>
   <li class="class3 class4">Content<li>
   <li class="class3 class4 class1">Content<li>
   <li class="class3 class4 class5">Content<li>
   <li class="class3 class4 class1">Content<li>
</ul>
```

Now I want display maximum posts on each class from above list is 3. For example: `class1` appear 5 times from top to bottom. But I want keep only 3. (From top to bottom)

I am using [filter](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/). When class is active, it appears more than number of posts I want. How can I do it with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're saying that for each class you only want the first three elements that have that class, then do this:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
    $("#portfolio-list li.class" + i).slice(3).remove();
```

---

Since you said the class names are random, then amass them all, and iterate the list.

```
var classes = $("#portfolio-list li[class]").map(function(el) {
    return el.className.split(/\s+/);
}).toArray();

classes = $.grep(classes, function(clss, i) {
    return clss && $.inArray(clss, classes) === i;
});

$.each(classes, function(i, clss) {
    $("#portfolio-list li." + clss).slice(3).remove();
});
```

---

Instead of the last `$.each()`, we could do this:

```
var before = "#portfolio-list li.",
    after = ":gt(2)";

$(before + classes.join(after + ", " + before) + after).remove();
```

If the classes were `"foo"`, `"bar"`, `"baz"` and `"buz"`, the resulting selector would look like this:

```
"#portfolio-list li.foo:gt(2), #portfolio-list li.bar:gt(2), #portfolio-list li.baz:gt(2), #portfolio-list li.buz:gt(2)"
```

Though it may be more efficient to do this:

```
$("portfolio-list").find("li." + classes.join(":gt(2), li.") + ":gt(2)").remove();
```

Or this:

```
$("portfolio-list").find("li")
                   .filter("." + classes.join(":gt(2), .") + ":gt(2)").remove();
```

Or this:

```
$("portfolio-list").find("li." + classes.join(", li."))
                   .filter(":gt(2)").remove();
```

Comment: Thanks. but class name is any name, not in order. (just for example purpose only)

Comment: @user2728514: If the class name is random, then you'll need to amass all the classes on all the LI's first. See the update.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am updating.

Comment: Hello. Now if I want check through opacity. If li that have opacity:1, it is displayed. But maximum li for display is 3 only. Please help me check demo:http://jsfiddle.net/9LQz8/ and help me for complete it. (current is class1 with opacity:1) Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try [.slice()](https://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++ )
{
    $('#"portfolio-list .class1').slice("3")
}
```

---

Update after OP's comment

```
var cls_list = [];
$('#portfolio-list li').each(function () { //loop through each li item
    var cls = $.trim($(this).attr('class')).split(' '); //get list of classes in array using split with space
    for (var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++) { //loop through list of classes
        if (cls_list.indexOf(cls[i]) === -1 && $.trim(cls[i]) != '') { //check if not in array and not empty
            cls_list.push(cls[i]);//push to array 
            $('#portfolio-list li.' + cls[i]).slice("3"); //.remove() or .hide();
        }
    }
});
```

---

Correct You html too

```
<li class="class1 class2">Content</li> //close li tags
//                                ^
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z58qP/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. I want for all class, not only one.

Comment: Thanks. but class name is any name (not in order as given example)

Comment: Ok. I am checking. Thank much for your help and @cookie's help